# Parse EDIFACT UN in Python

Tags: python, regex, edifact

I need to parse EDIFACT message in python.
To find segment e.g UNB I am trying to use regex

```
pattern = "UNB(.*?)(?<!\?)(\?\?)*[']"
```

and test string

```
message = "UNA+456+6:54+654'UNB+64+654+54?'UNC+54+654+654'"
```

Segment delimeter is **'** (apostrophe) and **?** is escape char.
In RegexCoach  the match string is **UNB+64+654+54?'UNC+54+654+654'**
That is right becouse the first apostrophe after UNB is escaped
But in Python 3.5

```
re.match(pattern,message)
```

return None :( Do you have idea where is error?
Or suggestion for another solution?

Thank
test:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/N_IJcS-L4hz5_xdu)

Comment: Is this your actual code? `patter` isn't defined and I got a SyntaxError when I tried `pattern = 'UNB(.*?)(?<!\?)(\?\?)*[']'  `.

Comment: I can't produce any result. Are you sure the pattern you provided is *exactly* as you are using it?

Comment: patter is typo error. Right pattern.

Comment: Yes, pattern is exactly the same. I try it in RegexCoach application and it's working. But in Python does not work.

Comment: Try BOTS, open source Python EDI translator: http://bots.sourceforge.net/en/about_features.shtml

Comment: I parse the EDI messages with regexes, you could see if you can port it to python. My approach if to split the message in different steps, segments, data elements, composite data elements. See an older version of the package https://github.com/php-edifact/edifact/blob/3bd7205d3e1d9fe9bc3f94cdb4ad40f7ee9dea11/src/EDI/Parser.php (the newer version contain parameters to deal with UNA changes).